# No ethernet connection in dual boot with Windows 10 and Kubuntu

Tags: networking, dual-boot, kubuntu, internet, ethernet

I am currently dual booting Kubuntu (20.04.1 LTS) and Windows 10 (should be up to date).

I only started doing this yesterday and at the beginning everything worked fine. However after switching to Windows to export some config files and then switching back to Kubuntu I had no Internet (at all) and no Sound (USB Headset). Both of these still work as of right now (typing this in Windows 10).

Im on a Ethernet connection with a Realtek controller (on my motherboard), Windows won't say much more but this is the driver version: 10.37.1028.2019

My Headset is a Sound blaster XH6, also working fine on Windows but getting Ethernet working is my priority right now.

Here is the (probably incomplete list) of what I tried:

- Shutting down Windows instead of restarting
- Disabling "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" in Device Manager
- Enabling/Disabling "Shutdown Wake-On-Lan" in Device Manager
- Running `ipconfig /release` before exiting Windows
- Setting up a new Ethernet connection in Kubuntu

I am out of ideas from myself and already looked at tons of questions, none having an answer that also helped me.

Please tell me if I need to provide more information.

Edit:
Output of running lscpi on Kubuntu: https://pastebin.com/shmkpzRc

Comment: It's doubtful that anything in Windows is affecting your Kubuntu installation. Have you updated Kubuntu recently? Can you update your question to show the output of `lspci`? This will show whether Kubuntu understands it has an ethernet port or not.

Comment: edited the original post

Comment: Missed the updating part: Yes I updated it before going to Windows @Matigo

Answer (score 0):

Solved by switching to an older kernel (Advanced Options at boot)